# Can I conclude that $xz = y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is for homework, so I would appreciate just a hint or suggestion.  I am asked

> Identify the group $G = \langle x, y, z \mid x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = e, xz = zx, xyx = yxy, zyz = yzy \rangle$.

I started by trying to fill out the multiplication table.  However, when I get to evaluating $xz$ I am stuck.  I can see that $xz \neq e, x, z$, but can I deduce that $xz = y$?  I know that $Q_8$ is generated by $i$ and $j$ under specific relations, so I cannot simply say that $xz = y$ because $xz \neq e, x, z$.  I need to use the relations in some clever way, but am not seeing it.  If I can get $xz = y$ then I will be done.  Any suggestions?

Comment: $xz= y$ can't be right I guess, if you plug in this equality in the equality $zyz= yzy$ then we have $zxzz= xzzxz$ which reduces to $zx= z$ that's evidently not correct. I hope I made no mistake with the calculations.

Comment: @aranya You are completely right.  Looks like $xz$ is some new element.  Thank you!

Comment: I feel that we need introduce a new element in $G$ so we can then omit $x$ for example. Moreover, $y^2=z^2=(zy)^3$ give us your friend $S_4$. Tietze method is needed here.

Comment: How exactly do you see that $xz \ne e,x,z$?

Comment: @DerekHolt If $xz = x$ or $xz = z$, then cancellation implies $z = e$ or $x = e$, respectively.  If $xz = e$, then multiplying both sides on the left by $x$ implies $z = x$.

Comment: @tylerc0816: That's true, but none of those conclusions are necessarily false - they do not contradict anything. The group $G$ could have order 1. (Of course, we know now that $G \cong S_4$, but in general you cannot just assume that the generators in a group presentation are not equal to the identity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that out of old habit I am writing $1$ for $e$. Also, $a^{b} = b^{-1} a b$.

**Hint 1**

> $(x y)^3 = 1$, and similarly $(z y)^{3} = 1$.

**Hint 2**

> $(x z (x z)^y)^{2} = 1$

**Hint 3**

> $V = \langle x z, (xz)^y\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of order at most $4$.

**Hint 4**

> $\langle V, x y \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of order at most $12$, and index at most $2$.

**Hint 5**

> The relations are satisfied in $S_{4}$ if you take $x = (1,2)$, $y = (2,3)$, $z = (3,4)$.

Comment: Very nice Andreas. I was doing some Todd-Coxeter method for the group, but you was so fast and this post really makes clear us what is going on inside the group. +1

Comment: Thanks @B.S. Perhaps I should clarify that I asked GAP for help, so I should have started from the very bottom.

Comment: That's Ok. By the way, a very latest version of [GAP 4.6.5](http://www.gap-system.org/) released. :-)

Comment: @B.S., whooops! I had installed the previous one only a few days ago... Thanks for the info.

Comment: How can one show that $V$ and $\langle V,xy\rangle$ are normal subgroups?